# Write to custom section in app.config .Net

Tags: .net, wpf, c#-4.0, app-config

I am using .Net 4.0 on a WPF application with MVVM
I have added a custom section **MyAppCustom.ReportServer.Settings** to the section group **userSettings** as below:

```
<sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b87a6a562548e011" >
  <section name="MyApp.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b87a6a562548e011" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
  <section name="MyAppCustom.ReportServer.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b87a6a562548e011" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
</sectionGroup>

<userSettings>
<MyApp.Properties.Settings>
  <setting name="Timezone" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Asia/Calcutta</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="Language" serializeAs="String">
    <value>en_US</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="SSO" serializeAs="String">
    <value>True</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="LoginPeriod" serializeAs="String">
    <value>480</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="FirstLaunch" serializeAs="String">
    <value>True</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="IP" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="Port" serializeAs="String">
    <value />
  </setting>
  <setting name="ReportServer" serializeAs="String">
    <value>http://10.2.130.121/ReportServer</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="Reports" serializeAs="String">
    <value>/MyReports/UserReport</value>
  </setting>
</BallyTech.UserMatrix.Properties.Settings>
<MyAppCustom.ReportServer.Settings>
  <setting name="UserName" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Administrator</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
    <value>admin</value>
  </setting>
  <setting name="Domain" serializeAs="String">
    <value></value>
  </setting>
</BallyTech.UserMatrix.ReportServer.Settings>
```

I am reading these settings in the below manner:

```
System.Configuration.Configuration config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection configClient = ((System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection)(config.GetSection("userSettings/MyAppCustom.ReportServer.Settings")));

string userName = configClient.Settings.Get("UserName").Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
string password = configClient.Settings.Get("Password").Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
```

The **userName** and **password** refer to login information for the server where **SSRS reports server** has been installed from where I am fetching the reports and showing through ReportViewer in my application on the client.

Considering that I should not be saving the credentials in my app.config as plain text, I have 2 methods to encrypt and decrypt the app.config sections:

```
public static void EncryptConfigSection(string sectionName)
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationSection configSection = config.GetSection(sectionName);
        if (configSection != null)
        {
            if (!configSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
            {
                if (!configSection.ElementInformation.IsLocked)
                {
                    configSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider");
                    configSection.SectionInformation.ForceSave = true;
                    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void DecryptConfigSection(string sectionName)
    {
        System.Configuration.Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        ConfigurationSection configSection = config.GetSection(sectionName);
        if (configSection != null)
        {
            if (!(configSection.SectionInformation.IsLocked))
            {
                configSection.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection(); config.Save();
            }
        } 
    }
```

I want to make this userName and password configurable by the user in case the report server is changed. So, I would provide an interface for user to provide the report server name, report path and the credentials for that server. I am not able to figure out as to what would be the way to write the user provided credentials to this section and be able to save it and refresh settings on runtime.

I do not want to use **MyApp.Properties.Settings** section to save the credentials information as I am using it a lot of times in my app through **Properties.Settings.Default.[PropertyName]** and encrypting and decrypting all the information would be unnecessary.

**Also, I am open to any alternate idea where I can save the credentials and be able to encrypt it and read it in my application.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never write to web.config or app.config, that sits in your app directory.

1. Most likely the in the production, the folder will be readonly.
2. ASP.Net in particular, monitors any changes inside the folder with application, and will recycle AppPool everytime you write anything to web.config. Also, this will happen everytime you write any file to your application folder.

So, to make all this work, you should create a separate folder (not under your web app folder), and store a separate config there.

In order to open config at custom location you should use code like the following:

```
var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
configMap.ExeConfigFilename = "your full path to the config";
var customConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```

Also, here's a sample folder structure for a web app:

- C:\YourApp - the root of app.
- C:\YourApp\Config - folder for custom configs
- C:\YourApp\Data - folder for some user-generated data, e.g. uploaded files.
- C:\YourApp\Web - the actual web application folder mapped in IIS. You should never write or change any file here from your application code, or IIS will recycle your app pool.