# change session timeout in web.config programatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-config, session-timeout

I have a requirement where i have to change connection string and session time out programatically, both need to be written in web.config and saved on hard disk. I could change connection string as below but struggling to accomplish the same for session timeout, could that be done someways?

```
 var configuration = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
 var section = configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
 section.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString = "Data Source=...";
 configuration.Save();
```

Comment: Post the code to set the session timeout

Comment: Why do you need to programmatically change the web.config?  That's not safe.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you need to alter the config settings? Not, I hope, during running of the actual app? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: It's almost as if you want to change the connection strings upon deployment to another environment?  If so, there are standard ways to achieve this.  Programmatically modifying the web.config is not the way to go.

Comment: session time out and connection string passwords are saved in database and database people do not have access to application server

Comment: But application people have access to the db.  Could you just read session timeout from the DB?  Clearly you cannot read the connection string for the db as you need the connection string to connect to the db.

Comment: @Blam i read session timeout from db, but is dere any way to save that in web.config?

Comment: Not sure how.   See this for reasons not to do it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800498/write-to-custom-section-in-app-config-net

Answer (score 0):

This short question-answer string shows [how to set the timeout programmatically](http://forums.asp.net/t/319449.aspx/1).  Like others have said, I'm not sure why you'd be required to do this but if you are, you are.